# Filter groups using a lagged column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on creating some error reports and one of the times I'm trying to address is potential errors within the ID column `id_1`. I've made an alternative id column from various identifying features within the rows that I'm calling `id_2`. To help, I've also created a `date_lag` column on `date` to catch items that were entered within a specific period after the initial entry. The main problem that I'm having is returning the entire group that meets the criteria, including that first entry that would have an `NA` in the `date_lag`, or, if I allow the `NA` values through, I get more than just the items I'm looking for (`id_1` 1 and 2 below).
Example:

```
#id_1  where potential errors lie
#id_2  alternative id col I'm using to test
df <- data.table(id_1 = c(1:4, 1:4),
                 id_2 = c(rep(c("b", "a"), c(2, 2))),
                 date = c(rep(1,4),rep(20,2), rep(10,2)))

df %>%
  group_by(id_2) %>%
  mutate(date_lag = date - lag(date)) %>%
  filter(between(date_lag, 0, 10) | is.na(date_lag))
    
    # A tibble: 6 x 4
    # Groups:   id_1 [4]
     id_1 id_2   date date_lag
  <int> <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
     1     b         1       NA
     2     b         1        0
     3     a         1       NA
     4     a         1        0
     2     b        20        0
     3     a        10        9
     4     a        10        0
```

Expected:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id_2 [4]
id_1 id_2      value val_lag
<int> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
  3     a         1      NA
  4     a         1      NA
  3     a        10       9
  4     a        10       9
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, we can use `diff`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id_1) %>% 
    filter(between(diff(date), 0, 10))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id_1 [2]
#   id_1 id_2   date
#  <int> <chr> <dbl>
#1     3 a         1
#2     4 a         1
#3     3 a        10
#4     4 a        10
```

---

Concatenate with `NA` as the `diff` returns a length 1 less than the original data

```
df %>%
    group_by(id_2) %>% 
    filter(between(c(NA, diff(date)), 0, 10))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   id_2 [2]
#   id_1 id_2   date
#  <int> <chr> <dbl>
#1     2 b         1
#2     4 a         1
#3     2 b        20
#4     3 a        10
#5     4 a        10
```

Comment: I can't get that code to run, issues with the 'lag' and 'differences'

Comment: `Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 4 or 1, not size 3.
i Input `..1` is `between(diff(date), 0, 10)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: id_2 = "a".`

Comment: @Reed I got the result with your example data which I posted

Comment: Ah, I see the issue, I amended to mention that I'm actually grouping by `id_2` as that's my alternative ID and when I use `id_2` I get that error

Comment: @Reed Is the expected output in your post based on the id_2 or id_1?  I updated the post

Comment: I see that it's an error in the testing dataset, there's duplicated rows leading to the error

Comment: @Reed can you show an example that gives the error so that it can be tested

Comment: It was based on `id_2` I forgot to update that portion in the edit. Thanks for catching that.